# How to catch javascript event in angular 2 project with a java rest service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, web-applications, angular

once again I want to apologize for the lack of proper vocabulary.

My case is as follows: I have a webpage (web application??) I am building with angular2. There, I have a javascript function that gives me a nice calendar. Front end stuff.

Then, I am doing, with Java, a REST service that is going to receive the date selected in the calendar, and operate with it.

Now, I am not sure if I am missing a step between this two things. I want to know what HAS to happen for the web application to send the info to the rest service (it's going to be deployed on tomcat, for what is worth).

So far I've been told that something like this will do the job:

http://offering.solutions/articles/angular/rest-api-angular2-http-typescript/

https://github.com/Paldom/angular2-rest

But I fail to understand how does that work, am I missing an additional step, or would that suffice?

My understanding of the process is the following: Picking a date on the calendar trigers an event, it gets catched (with angular2 code), sent (how?) to the rest service, and then processed.

Are there additional steps? Concepts I might be missing? If I could get some guidance, even at purely theoretical level, I feel it would help me greatly. Thanks in advance.

edit: calendar code:

```
function myCalendar(){
  $('.datepicker').pickadate({
    formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
        selectYears: 15 // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
        });
}
```

Comment: Depends on your calendar library, how things are wired up in background.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but it's wired easily, it's a pickadate function that I then import in a certain component in angular2, and use it, @rinukkusu . Was that what you meant?

Comment: Yes that's the general direction I was aiming at. Could you show in your question how you retrieve a date in your code?

Comment: It's really nothing special, just using libraries that already exist and do the job. I believe, at least so, at least. If you need anything else do tell me, project is messy so I didn't think simply dumping every file would really help, so ask for anything else necesary @rinukkusu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would do what you're describing:

```
import {Http} from '@angular/http'

class Picker {
  constructor(private http:Http) {
    document.getElementByID('date-picker')
      .addEventListener('date-picker-event-or-whatever', date => this.send(date));
  }

  send(date) {
    this.http
      .post('some/rest/api', JSON.stringify(date))
      .map(reposne => response.json())
      .subscribe(json => console.log(json));
  }
}
```

Note that this isn't a real code, just a principle. You'll have to decide where you want to do this (component, service...), how to catch/trigger events, etc.

Comment: thanks!! that looks great and not the same that what I saw, but similar, so that's neat. Would you mind telling me if this... operation? has a name?? I have seen "consuming REST api with (angular2)", but I'm not sure that's correct/all there's to it.